# Convert XAML-Canvas to bitmap

Tags: xaml

I need to convert a large amount of icons in XAML format (all just use canvas) to bitmap format.

Does anybody know about a tool that does that?
I only found xamltoys/xaml2emf. This works but not correctly - colors are messed up and resolution is very low.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code I did will just allow you to save **any** FrameworkElement to disk:

```
Public Shared Sub SaveImageOfControlToDisk(ByVal MyControl As FrameworkElement, ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim ThisVisualBrush As New VisualBrush(MyControl)
    Dim ThisDrawingVisual As New DrawingVisual()
    Dim dc As DrawingContext = ThisDrawingVisual.RenderOpen()
    dc.DrawRectangle(ThisVisualBrush, Nothing, New Rect(New Point(), New Size(MyControl.ActualWidth, MyControl.ActualHeight)))
    dc.Close()
    Dim render As New RenderTargetBitmap(MyControl.ActualWidth, MyControl.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
    render.Render(ThisDrawingVisual)
    Dim PngEncoder As New PngBitmapEncoder()
    PngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(render))
    Dim ThisStream As New IO.FileStream(FileName, IO.FileMode.Create)
    PngEncoder.Save(ThisStream)
    ThisStream.Flush()
    ThisStream.Close()
End Sub
```