# Convert an HTML output into an Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a web page which was written on ASP.NET and C#. it outputs a HTML code. Want to output an image instead. How do i do it?

Thanks

Comment: @megazoid do you want to get the webpage as a image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-export-webpage-as-image-in.html) to convert HTML to image.
You can try it out. It is available for **FREE**.

or

you can use this one [web page save as a image](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-export-webpage-as-image-in.html) to get the webpage output as image

Answer (score 0):

Since the control in charge of dispalying the web page is like any other element, you might save its render to a file :
[Convert XAML-Canvas to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715543/convert-xaml-canvas-to-bitmap/8104089#8104089)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your web page as the href of an anchor and return a dynamic image based on some query string then you could use Response object to send your image stream using Response.BinaryWrite object and set Content Type to appropriate image.